# Как получить остаток в Питоне?

Tags: python

> Напиши программу, которая принимает два целых числа: количество коллег и задач.
> Программа должна вывести два целых числа:
> • количество задач, которые достанутся каждому коллеге;
> • остаток задач, которые перейдут главному в команде.
> Пример 1: Пользователь ввёл:
> 3
> 6
> Программа должна вывести:
> 2
> 0

```
s1 = int(input())
s2 = int(input())
s3 = s2//s1
s4 = s3//s2
print(s3)   #сдесь ошибка может тут нужен %, или, как то по-другому. 
print(s4)
```

что нужно добавить, что вывести остаток.

Comment: какая же неведомая сила помешала просто проверить "может тут нужен %"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот ответ:

```
s1 = int(input())
s2 = int(input())
s3 = s2 // s1
s4 = s2 % s1 # поменяла // на %
print(s3)
print(s4)
```

a % b - таким образом можно получить остаток от деления а на b
В s3 просто делим нацело
В s4 получаем остаток

Answer (score 1):

```
s1, s2 = int(input('s1: ')), int(input('s2: '))
s3, s4 = divmod(s1, s2)  # возвращается сразу и частное и остаток в кортеже, например  (2,0)
print(s3, s4)
```

```
s1: 6
s2: 3
2 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Задача крайне проста. Советую не задавать вопросов здесь на такие простые задачи а искать решение в гугл или яндекс, но ваше стремление в программировании я не могу не оценить и пройти мимо и не помочь вам.

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
print(a//b)
print(a%b)
```

Удачи в дальнейшем программировании и решении задач.